# Any light weight alternatives to Visual Studio for testing code snippets?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

Are there any light weight tools (preferably portable so I can put it in a memory stick) that can compile C# code snippets? I don't want to load Visual Studio, create a project and all to test a small code snippet.

Thansks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775055/looking-for-replacement-for-snippet-compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about http://rextester.com/rundotnet?

This is online - so always available - downsides are it's a little slow, so good for trying out simple things quickly - not so great if you're doing anything more complex.

> Alternatively if you want an offline approach try Linq Pad
>
> http://www.linqpad.net/

Although it was primarily created to debug LINQ statements - it actually works as a great lightweight general purpose IDE.

Comment: I never realized we could use LINQPad as a general purpose IDE. It works great!

Answer (score 1):

[SnippetCompiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/) would be one, though it hasn't been updated for a while so could be out of date.

Edit: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775055/looking-for-replacement-for-snippet-compiler for more up-to-date alternatives

Comment: Looks good but it hasn't been updated since 2007 and no .NET 4 support.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a lightweight version of Visual Studio. It is essentially just the
packages required to get `MSBuild.exe` working.

The installer is a PowerShell script that sets the necessary variables, registry
keys and files.

Comparison

[Visual Studio 2013](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40787)

790 MB

[Velour](http://github.com/svnpenn/velour)

168 MB